# adding to dict variable in list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts like this:

```
students=
    [
    {rollno:1,firstname:f1,last_name:l1,total_marks:0},
    {rollno:2,firstname:f2,last_name:l2,total_marks:0},
    {rollno:3,firstname:f3,last_name:l3,total_marks:0}
    ]
```

Then I get input in a loop in the form of

```
    rollno:1 english_marks:10
    rollno:2 english_marks:20
    rollno:5 social_marks: 30
    rollno:6 maths_marks:40
    rollno:1 science_marks:30
    rollno:2 science_marks:40
```

Now I want to add all subject marks related to correct roll number `total_marks` variable.
How can I achieve this?

```
for marks in marks_list:
   students[rollno] = ...?  # need help here : how can I access total_marks variable of that rollno?
```

Answer (score 0):

Because students is a list, with no key, you can't index it with anything other than an int, which doesn't help you if you are trying to use the `rollno` as a key. Assuming you want to use the data structures you've shown (and not create new data structures,) you must loop over the list of students to find the one with the `rollno` you want.

```
for marks in marks_list:
  for student in students:
    if student[rollno] == marks[rollno]:
       # you found the student whose rollno matches that of the mark, so do your stuff here
```

There are other ways to do this with shorthand, find, etc. but since you say you are new to Python, I think it's best to see the raw loops doing the work.

Note that you should never modify any collection while looping over it. So be sure to create a copy or new list if you want to save any mutations of the data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...if we can edit students data structure....how do you suggest it should look like...so that addition will be easy

Comment: IMO, the students data structure should be a dictionary with the key as the rollno, and the value as the rest of the dict: `students = {1: {firstname:f1,last_name:l1,total_marks:0}, {2: ...`

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something similar to this, assuming your `students` object and a list of tuples (i.e. `(1, "maths_mark", 90)`) names `marks_list`:

```
# Set up your basic data structure
student_roll = {r.get("rollno"): {
    "firstname": r.get("firstname", "unknown"),
    "lastname": r.get("lastname", "unknown"),
    "total_marks": 0,
    "marks": {}
} for r in students}

# Convert your values into that structure
for (roll_no, mark, score) in marks_list:
    roll = students_roll.get(roll_no)
    marks = roll.get("marks", {})
    score_list = marks.get(mark, [])
    score_list.append(score)
    marks[mark] = score_list
    # do the appropriate math to update r[total_marks] = ...
    student_roll[roll_no] = roll
```

This will produce a dictionary that looks something like:

```
{
  1: {
    "firstname": "Joe",
    "lastname": "DeFalt",
    "total_marks": 20,
    "marks": {
      "english_marks": [10, 20],
      "math_marks": [30]
    },
  2: {
    "firstname": "Jessica",
    "lastname": "Bambino",
    "total_marks": 90,
    "marks": {
      "social_marks": [100, 70],
      "math_marks": [100]
    },
}
```